# Regex to find data in specific column of a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to search a document for data on a specific column. I am trying to use:

```
^.{x}[data to find]
```

where x is the number of columns I want - 1.

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if my regex engine does not support that syntax. I am trying to use Notepad++, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update 2013-2014 (4-5 years later)

As mentioned by [Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-moore) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557682/regex-to-find-data-in-specific-column-of-a-line/557975?noredirect=1#comment35837800_557975)

> [Notepad++ v6.x](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html) has real regex support via the PCRE library

See "[How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions#Multiplying_operators)" (Multiplying operators)

---

Original answer (February 2009)

I just checked with the latest Notepad++5.2 and its [regexp feature](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions).

I confirm it does not have any [repetition operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{min,max}` which would have allowed you to specify how many times a token can be repeated.

[image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_RrGIVCQs3RU/SHbq1B0wYlI/AAAAAAAAALI/h21UEYMEivc/s400/np%2B%2Breplace.png]

An alternative would be:

```
.... [repeat '.' as many time as the number of column you want] ...[data to find]
```

You do not need `^`: by default, Notepad++ regexps are applied line-by-line, and the `.` does not match eol characters (`\r` or `\n`)

---

As [Asmor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18210/asmor) mentions in the comments:

> Notepad++, for all its great features, uses Scintilla and inherits Scintilla's regex processing, with its limited [regex features](http://scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html).
>
> You say that "by default" regexes are applied line by line. This implies that you can set it otherwise, but to the best of my knowledge (and please, I beg you, prove me wrong!), there's no way to make multi-line regexes.

(I agree, and that is a *major* limitation)

> Another limitation of Scintilla, the `^` operator is actually important, as it anchors the regex to the beginning of the line. Say you wanted to match 3 in the third column. You would want `^..3`, and `..3` would match `3` in any column past the second.

Comment: Notepad++, for all its great features, uses Scintilla and inherits Scintilla's regex processing. Here's a list of the features: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html It's a limited feature set relative to e.g. Perl, but it's better than some...

Comment: You say that "by default" regexes are applied line by line. This implies that you can set it otherwise, but to the best of my knowledge (and please, I beg you, prove me wrong!), there's no way to make multi-line regexes. Another limitation of Scintilla.

Comment: (Sorry for all the comments, but I have three distinct points to make, and I figured multiple comments would be the best way) The ^ operator is actually important, as it anchors the regex to the beginning of the line. Say you wanted to match 3 in the third column. You would want ^..3, and ..3 would match 3 in any column past the second.

Comment: Just so you know, Notepad++ v6+ has real regex support via the PCRE library.

Comment: @AlanMoore Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as added some links to illustrate that new 6.x feature.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is much more suited to this kind of task if you have access to it.

It doesn't look like notepad++ has a {x} feature from the documentation I can find.